Unbound module Eio-posix
I am trying to disable Windows symlinking tests in my OCaml code. However, when I run my tests, I encounter the following error message: Unbound module: Eio_posix
I installed the Eio library using opam, following the instructions from the Eio documentation. I'm not sure if I'm missing a step or if there's an issue with how I’m referencing the module.
open Eio.Std

let () = Printexc.record_backtrace true

module L = Eio_posix.Low_level



I expected this to work based on the documentation, but it seems like the module Eio_posix cannot be found. Any insights on why this might be happening or how to properly disable Windows symlinking tests in OCaml would be appreciated!

How are you compiling/building this program?

I am compiling the program using ocamlfind with the following command:  ocamlfind ocamlc -o open_beneath -package eio,alcotest,eio.unix -linkpkg open_beneath.ml.  Initially, I didn't explicitly include eio_posix in the command. However, when I tried to include itI still encountered the Unbound module Eio_posix error.
I've installed all dependencies via opam as listed in the eio documentation, and opam list confirms that eio_posix is installed. I'm running this on Windows, which I suspect might have platform-specific limitations, but I'm unsure if that’s the issue.

Unless you are compiling/running this inside WSL (which is more-or-less just an ubuntu vm) there isn't posix compatibility on Windows. Perhaps if you could explain more about exactly what "windows symlinking tests" you are having problems with?

The Eio_posix is part of the eio_posix library:
ocamlfind ocamlopt -thread -package eio_posix name.ml -linkpkg -o name

